# How do I add a removeEventListener to a click event?

Tags: javascript, function, events

I searched online on how to disable an event, but everything was so confusing. I wonder if anyone could explain to me how I can disable a click event? Please comment if you have any questions. Thank you in advance! Someone told me to use a function, but I don't understand.

```js
//here are the variables that I used in this section of code so you can understand it better
var monsters = ["slug", "zombie", "wasp"];
var randomForMon = Math.floor(Math.random() * monsters.length);
var randMonster = monsters[randomForMon];
var user_answer = getNumber("answer_input");

//I don't need to put anything in this function (do I?), I just want to disable a button if the user tries to click it.
function handleClick(event) {
  //what would I even put here?
}

//when monster clicked, show fighting symbol and change screen
onEvent(randMonster, "click", function( ){
  hideElement("clickMonster_label");
  showSymbol();
  setTimeout(function(){
    setScreen("equation_screen");
  }, 1300);
  newEquation();
  if ("answer_input" !== "user_answer") {
    //I would add removeEventListener here so that player cannot click monster if their answer is incorrect.
  }
});
```

Just letting you know, I don't know much about JavaScript, so maybe use simpler terms xD. I would really appreciate it! Again, if you have any questions, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to track answers for each monster, and if the are incorrect, do not allow the user to click the monster again. To do this with your current architecture, below I setup an array of answers initially set to null, meaning no answer has been given. Within the click event, we will set the monsterAnswer to be true or false based on the user's response. Hope this helps and welcome!

```js
var monsters = ["slug", "zombie", "wasp"];
var randomForMon = Math.floor(Math.random() * monsters.length);
var randMonster = monsters[randomForMon];
var user_answer = getNumber("answer_input");
var monstersAnswers = [null, null, null];


//when monster clicked, show fighting symbol and change screen
onEvent(randMonster, "click", function() {
  const monsterAnswer = monstersAnswers[randomForMon];
  if (monsterAnswer === false) {
    // don't do anything
    return;
  }
  hideElement("clickMonster_label");
  showSymbol();
  setTimeout(function() {
    setScreen("equation_screen");
  }, 1300);
  newEquation();
  var userAnswer = /* something */

  monstersAnswers[randomForMon] = correctAnswer === userAnswer;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just return in the click listener when the "answer_input" !== "user_answer".